# Convert vertical list to horizontal one row datatable

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of double type values that I want to insert into datatable and bind it to datagridview with datetime headers. so how can I bind this list like this

list items :

1234

1478

45689

to this in datatable
01/12/2015    02/2/2015   03/2/2015

1234                 1478          45689

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how dates relate to your list but...

```
Dim l As New List(of String)()
l.Add("1234")
l.Add("5678")
l.Add("9012")

Dim columns as New List(of String)()
Dim data as New List(of String)()

Dim ddl as New StringBuilder(1000)
ddl.Append("Create Table MySchema.MyTable (") 

For i As integer = 0 To l.Count - 1
    ddl.Append("Column" & (i + 1).ToString() & " varchar(100)")
    If i < l.Count -1 Then 
        ddl.Append(",")
    End If
    columns.Add("Column" & (i + 1).ToString())
    data.Add("'" & l(i) & "'")
Next

ddl.Append(")") 

'--- Some ADO code here to create connection/command
 . . . . . . 
'---
command.CommantText = ddl.ToString()
command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Dim sql as String = "Insert into MySchema.MyTable ({0}) Values ({1})"
sql = String.Format(sql, string.Join(",", columns.ToArray()), string.Join(",", data.ToArray()))

command.CommantText = sql
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**Disclamer** COde is not tested

Comment: Hi, sorry if badly explained, I had pulled some data (type of double) from an excel file based on todays week and i was able to bind it to a datatable. in data table I added this week date as headers but I don't how to add each value from excel to each column in datatable. like first value goes the first column, 2nd value to second column... so on. thank you